# Can I change the way key pair data is stored to make the access very efficient?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array that contains user data. There are only about 20 elements in thsi data. I get this from my server and it is stored locally:

```
var userdata1 = 
[
{"id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4","name":"xxx"},
{"id":"e87c05bc-8305-45d0-ba07-3dd24438ba8b","name":"yyy"}
]
```

I have been using the following function to get the user name from my userProfiles array.

```
  $scope.getUser = function (userId) {
       if (userId && $scope.option.userProfiles)
           for (var i = 0; i < $scope.option.userProfiles.length; i++)
               if ($scope.option.userProfiles[i].id === userId)
                   return $scope.option.userProfiles[i].name;
       return '';
   }
```

I was looking for a more efficient way to get the name so I asked this question:

[How can I check an array for the first occurence where a field matches using _lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305143/how-can-i-check-an-array-for-the-first-occurence-where-a-field-matches-using-lo#21305143)

Now I am wondering. Is there another way that I could store my data to make it easier to access? One person suggested this
in the comments:

```
var usersdata2 = {someuserid: {id: "someusersid", name: 'Some Name'}, 
                 anotheruserid: {id: "anotheruserid", name: 'Another Name'}};
```

If I was to do this then would it be more efficient, how could I change my data from the first form userdata1 into userdata2
and how could I access it?

Comment: Use an object as a propertyname -> propertyvalue store!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform your array as follows:

```
var userMap = userdata1.reduce(function(rv, v) {
  rv[v.id] = v;
  return rv;
}, {});
```

That will give you an object that maps the "id" values onto the original object. You would then access the values like this:

```
var someUser = userMap[ someUserId ];
```

This set up will be **much** more efficient than your array, because finding an entry takes an amount of time proportional to the size of the "id" strings themselves (plus a little). In your version, you have to search through (on average) half the list for each lookup.  For a small set of records, the difference would be unimportant, but if you've got hundreds or thousands of them the difference will be huge.

The `.reduce()` function is not available in older browsers, [but there's a fill-in patch available on the MDN documentation site:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill)

```
// copied from MDN
if ('function' !== typeof Array.prototype.reduce) {
  Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback, opt_initialValue){
    'use strict';
    if (null === this || 'undefined' === typeof this) {
      // At the moment all modern browsers, that support strict mode, have
      // native implementation of Array.prototype.reduce. For instance, IE8
      // does not support strict mode, so this check is actually useless.
      throw new TypeError(
          'Array.prototype.reduce called on null or undefined');
    }
    if ('function' !== typeof callback) {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }
    var index, value,
        length = this.length >>> 0,
        isValueSet = false;
    if (1 < arguments.length) {
      value = opt_initialValue;
      isValueSet = true;
    }
    for (index = 0; length > index; ++index) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        if (isValueSet) {
          value = callback(value, this[index], index, this);
        }
        else {
          value = this[index];
          isValueSet = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!isValueSet) {
      throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty array with no initial value');
    }
    return value;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I like your solution and the explanation. Just out of interest. Is there anything in _lodash that would do the same as reduce or is reduce better. Note that I am targeting newer browsers only.

Comment: I think Lodash does have its own version of `.reduce()` which would work just as well. I'm not a Lodash user but I suspect it works in a very similar way.

Comment: I just tried your first example and it gives me an error saying id is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: @Marilou oh sorry; I'll fix the answer. I made an error when I copied if from the window I tested it in. It should be `rv[ v.id ]` instead of `rv[v[id]]` ...

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var usernames = {};
userdata1.forEach(function(u) {usernames[u.id] = u.name;});
alert(usernames[userId]);
```

(You'll either need a shim or a manual `for` loop to support older browsers - the above is intended to just give you an idea on how you can simplify your access)

Answer (score 0):

To make the access by ID more efficient copy the data into an object:

```
var userdata1 = 
[
{"id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4","name":"xxx"},
{"id":"e87c05bc-8305-45d0-ba07-3dd24438ba8b","name":"yyy"}
];
var userIdMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < userdata1.length; i++) {
    var item = userdata1[i];
    userIdMap[item.id] = item;
}
```

which means the function is now:

```
$scope.getUser = function (userId) {
   if (userId && $scope.option.userProfiles) {
       var user = userIdMap[userId];
       if(user)
           return user.name;
   }
   return '';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that puts your array items into a lookup object:

```
function arrayToLookup(array, idProperty) {
    var result = {};

    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[array[i][idProperty]] = array[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage would be like this, for your example:

```
var userdata1 = 
[
{"id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4","name":"xxx"},
{"id":"e87c05bc-8305-45d0-ba07-3dd24438ba8b","name":"yyy"}
]


// create a lookup object of your array.
// second parameter is the name of the property to use as the keys
var userDataLookup = arrayToLookup(userdata1, 'id');

// this is how you get a specific user out of the lookup
var user = userDataLookup["527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4"];
```