# Can I use _lodash to simplify the way I address an array of objects by using .reduce?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to do something similar to this question:

[Can I change the way key pair data is stored to make the access very efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311981/can-i-change-the-way-key-pair-data-is-stored-to-make-the-access-very-efficient)

I tried to use the function suggested in the answer but it gives me an error saying id is not defined:

```
var userMap = userdata1.reduce(function(rv, v) {
  rv[v[id]] = v;
  return rv;
}, {});
```

The user mentions that _lodash has something similar to .reduce.

Can I use _lodash to do the same thing which is to change:

```
var userdata1 = 
[
{"id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4","name":"xxx"},
{"id":"e87c05bc-8305-45d0-ba07-3dd24438ba8b","name":"yyy"}
]
```

into some object where I can find the name like this:

```
var theName = userdata1["527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4"]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the way key pair data is stored to make the access very efficient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311981/can-i-change-the-way-key-pair-data-is-stored-to-make-the-access-very-efficient); I've answered your question so that your immediate problem is solved but really once the ``rv[v[id]]`` bug is resolved, the answer to this question can be trivially derived from the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete solution:

```
var _ = require("lodash");

var userdata1 =
[
{"id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4","name":"xxx"},
{"id":"e87c05bc-8305-45d0-ba07-3dd24438ba8b","name":"yyy"}
];

var userMap = _.reduce(userdata1, function(rv, v) {
  rv[v.id] = v.name;
  return rv;
}, {});

console.log(userMap["527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4"]);
console.log(userMap["e87c05bc-8305-45d0-ba07-3dd24438ba8b"]);
```

Some notes:

1. I've included lodash as requested but you could just do it with a `userdata1.reduce`.
2. In the function you passed to `reduce` you were doing `rv[v[id]]`. This is why you got `undefined`. The code was not seeking the field named `"id"` from `v` it was trying to resolve the symbol named `id` in the current scope and found nothing defined with this name.
3. The only other modification to the anynymous function is to assgin `v.name` to the resulting object rather than `v` so that as requested in the question you get a **name** when accessing the `userMap` object.
4. Depending on your usage patterns it might be better to use `Object.create(null)` rather than `{}` in your call to `reduce`. Which is better depends on context.